# Did Tanisaki and Kashiwara publish a new book?

Tags: reference-request, books

Someone told me that Tanisaki and Kashiwara have a new book talking about affine flags and Schubert cells to calculate the intersection cohomologies and Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials. But he did not remember the title for the book. I searched on Google but found nothing. Anybody here know?

Comment: Kashiwara isn't involved, but you could conceivably be thinking of the 2008 book 'D-Modules, Perverse Sheaves and Representation Theory' by Hotta, Takeuchi and Tanisaki.
http://books.google.com/books?id=8ewkW5SC7DcC
They do a lot of general stuff with D-modules first, then get to the Kazhdan-Lusztig stuff near the end. A manuscript is available online at http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/Hotta.pdf , so if you didn't know about this book, check it out.